# Two columns - image, text - alignment not working

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

I have this in css:

```
.teamblock {
    position: relative;
}
.teamimage {
    float:left;
    width:20%
}
.teamtext {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width:60%;
}
```

In html, I structure as follows:

```
<div class="teamblock">
    <div class="teamimage">
        <img src="some image">
    </div>
    <div class="teamtext">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

At first it seemed to be working. But see here:

http://dev.pfp-consortium.org/index.php/about/meet-our-team

I can't figure out how this is possible...

thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything worng ... but I see you aren't clear the floated elements. Try fixing that http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: jep, u just need to add `clear:both` to your `.teamblock` selector - and, just for good-looking, add a little margin to it

Comment: Tell us what's definitely wrong? In what browser/op. system?

Answer (score 2):

This is also for the white width

so you have :

```
.teamblock{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 5px;
width: 100%;
background: #ffffff;
}
```

It works for me see: 
[image]

Comment: at the bottom of the page the last people isn't showing right see: http://puu.sh/dqbH5/ad010b5245.jpg

Comment: It depends on system preferences, default font-size, installed fonts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear after each one person, there is more ways how to do that. One of them is to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.teamblock`.

```
.teamblock {overflow: hidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `display: inline-block`.

```
.teamimage {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.teamtext {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Adding a class of 'clearfix' is needed in the container around the elements with the 'float' property.

Firstly add clear:both

```
.teamimage {
    clear:both;
}
```

Then add a clearfix to .teamblock like so:

add this in your css

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
```

Then edit the html and add the class to the div

```
<div class="teamblock clearfix" ></div>
```

Read all about clearfix here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Why you set first ... clearfix to inline-block and after as block .... and the `* html` part ... and another properties on the after element seems useless.

Comment: It's from CSS Tricks, its an enhanced version of the clearfix hack so it works better across all browsers.

Comment: You just copy / paste the first part you see ... At least read the entire post and you will see the updates leads to the simplest way you need ... wtih just three lines of code. If you know CSS you need to interpretate the code not just copy / paste

Comment: The simple version works for IE8 and up, I thought id just show the long version to make sure it works everywhere (below IE8), but yeah maybe I should have posted the short version.

Comment: Again if you read the post ... if you want support below IE8 just need to add the zoom part

Comment: Ok, so it seems that clearfix is the way to go? I am fairly new to this. How would I apply that to my existing css? thanks!

Comment: Yes definitely. Just add the clearfix section in your CSS (above) then add the class to the container wrapping around your floated elements. In your case 'teamblock' just as I have done in my post above.

Comment: Ok, that worked, thank you! Do you know how I would get the blocks to all extend to the same point horizontally? You can see on my page that they are all different. I followed someone's advice above, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: no problem :) width:100% on the .teamblock class should work.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! My brain is fried. I put width=